# What is a reasonable svn ignore list for python projects?

Tags: python, svn

I just setup an svn python project and would like to write a proper ignore list. Most people seem to ignore `__pycache__` and `*.py[cod]`, yet I feel the `*.pyd` files are required or am I wrong?
What other files would you add?

Answer (score 0):

Github has a bunch of pretty useful default ignore lists, I'm sure you can adjust those for SVN. (Any reason why you want to use SVN over git, by the way?)

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore